# How to check RadioButton of other Activity

Tags: java, android

How I can check one `RadioButton` of other `Activity` in Android?

I'm trying it with normal sentence but my app crash.

Comment: This question seems to indicate that you're trying to do something you shouldn't. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to do app for facture. You check what you want and when you press "Facture" I open new activity and in the new activity i test if the client mark radiobuttons or not.

Comment: Didn't quite understand, you check the RadioButton in the same activity you click "Facture"?

Comment: No, when i click "Facture" i open new activity when i what client check in the first Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Intent extras. Just pass the value of the RadioButton to the next Activity:

```
    Intent nextActivtyIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    nextActivtyIntent.putExtra("RadioButtonValue", "value");
    startActivity(nextActivtyIntent);
```

Then in SecondActivity you can get this value:

```
     String radioButtonValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("RadioButtonValue");
```

You can offcourse pass an Int (and other types as well) the same way, use whatever suits you best.

Read this for further info:
[Android Bundle](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this function?

**public void setChecked (boolean checked)**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked(boolean)